# Heroku's Spring MVC Hibernate template application not connecting to DB

Tags: jpa, spring-mvc, heroku

I'm trying to get the sample application running, but getting the following error when it tries to connect to the db:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
```

I haven't changed the applicationContext.xml, and the particular portion is:

```
    <beans profile="default">
    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource"/>        
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="prod">
    <bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
        <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="url" value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + @dbUrl.getPath() }"/>
        <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }"/>
        <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <!-- change this to 'verify' before running as a production app -->
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I am able to connect to the db using pgAdmin III from my laptop.
Also, I am learning Spring, and I see some beans are wrapped in the profile "prod", but I cannot tell anywhere in code or web.xml that uses a particular profile.
Does the application server (Heroku?) need to start in a particular mode/profile, could that be why the db connection is not opening?
I'm learning Heroku as well.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to run application on local machine? To be able to run this sample project on your local machine, you need to have database created. It's not described in the tutorial but if you try to use sample DATABASE_URL (`postgres://scott:tiger@localhost/myapp`) you need to create user `scott` with password `tiger` and create database `myapp` and grant `scott` required privileges. What I did, I've created `sampledb` database with existing `postgres` user, since it's database admin, I don't need to bother with grants and just changed url to

`export DATABASE_URL=postgres://postrges:<password>@localhost/sampledb`